# INSERT query of xampp MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

This php insert query is not working in MYSQL xampp. I couldn't find any error

**QUERY:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member (id, username,fname,lname,email, password, salt )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt' )";
```

Comment: Did u check apache logs?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The code you've shared does nothing else than building a horribly insecure database query. If you want to use it to insert data, please have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 1):

you are missing $fname, $lname in query also use NULL for id if auto incremented

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member (id, username,fname,lname,email, password, salt )
VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email', '$salt' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing wrong number of column names.your correct query should look like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member (username,password,email,salt )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting values to all the columns specified in the query.

In your query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member (id, username,fname,lname,email, password, salt )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt' )";
```

You are specifying 7 columns and only 4 values .So either add more values or remove unnecessary columns specified in the query like

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member (username, password,email, salt )
VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt' )";
```

OR

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member (id, username,fname,lname,email, password, salt )
VALUES ('$id', '$username','$fname','$lname','$email', '$password', '$salt' )";
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you need to ensure you have established a connection to the database and ensure you have the right code for example `

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}`
```

And perhaps try not using *NULL* in your insert VALUES statement

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that connecting to the database is the core problem?